# Laravel groupBy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, group-by

I'm trying to redesign my Laravel 4.2 code and like to group a list from results over the last days.

code:

```
public function getTrending($type = null, $category = null)
{
    $posts = $this->posts($type, $category)->with('comments', 'votes', 'category', 'user', 'votes.user')
        ->leftJoin('votes', 'posts.id', '=', 'votes.post_id')
        ->leftJoin('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id')
        ->select('posts.*', DB::raw('count(comments.post_id)*7 + count(votes.post_id)*30 + posts.views as popular'))
        ->groupBy('posts.id')->with('user')->orderBy('popular', 'desc')->whereMonth('posts.created_at', '>=', date('n', strtotime('-1 month')))
        ->paginate(perPage());

    return $posts;
}
```

I want to group the results as it is (relevance: comments, votes, visit) + grouping the results on a daily base.

Like:

Today (with Date xx.xx.xx)

- result 1 (Max Votes, Comment, ...)
- result 2
- result 3

Yesterday (with Date xx.xx.xx)

- result 4 (Max Votes, Comments, ...)
- result 5
- result 6

Is this possible?

Comment: use Carbon, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon;

```
->groupBy(function($date) {
        return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('Y'); // grouping by years
        //return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m'); // grouping by months
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

No I don't believe you can group your data in a single query like that.

Assuming your code is giving you the dataset you desire, without grouping by date, I would loop over the dates I want and get the data for every day and format it with the date heading etc.

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question and should be a comment in stead.